# Check input value in jquery using if else

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have an input box whose id is **sellingprice**. i want to check the input value in jquery using the if else condition and display the result value in an input box whose id is **result**.

example:

if the value in input box is greater **50** it will display in the other input box the word **too high**

### i'm a newbie in jquery and confused on how to implement it. Appreciate if someone may guide me through this.

I'll revised my question from above:

i have a table value something like this:

```
sellingprice      result

51                 ?
49                 ?
```

if the sellingprice value is greater than 50 this will be the calculation: **sellingprice - 50 * 0.05 + 3.5**

and if the sellingprice value is less than 50 the calculation will be: **sellingprice * 0.07;**

sorry i'm just trying to simplify my question but this is really the problem that i'm been facing as of this moment. Hope to guide me through this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[edit after your update]

```
var sp = $('#sellingprice').val() | 0;
if (sp <= 50) {
   $('#result').val(sp * 0.07)
}
else {
   $('#result').val(sp - 50 * 0.05 + 3.5) /* check the operations order */
}
```

where

```
$('#sellingprice').val() | 0
```

is an explicit (and more efficient than parseInt) int casting. If you can insert also floated point values change this statement with `var sp = parseFloat($('#sellingprice').val())`

with a ternary operator the code is simply reduced to

```
var sp = $('#sellingprice').val() | 0;
$('#result').val((sp <= 50)? sp - 50 * 0.05 + 3.5  : sp * 0.07)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#result').val(
    +$('#sellingprice').val() > 50 ? "too high" : "do backflips!"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var val = parseFloat($("#sellingprice").val());
var parsedVal = 0;

if (!isNaN(val))
{
  parsedVal = val;
}

if (parsedVal > 50)
{
   $("#result").val("Too High");
}
```